# OAuth and Google Groups Membership

Tags: drupal, google-oauth, google-groups-api

I am migrating some content from a Google Sites + Google groups setup to Drupal. In the current scenario: users request to join the Google Group, and the Google site permissions are configured to allow only group members to view it.

We need to migrate the Google Site to Drupal. Now Drupal can authenticate users using Google credentials using OAuth, but how do I check whether the user is a member of the google group as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think there is a way to check that on your site when using sign-in with Google. We don't pass that info in token and I don't think there are group APIs for you to use to do the validation.